# remix "no contract compiled yet" although contract is error free

Tags: remix, error

Im trying to run code on remix. But it's showing "no contract compiled yet" although contract is error free

My contract-

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Dwitter
{
    //state variables
    uint public dweetCounter;
    uint userCounter;
    address owner;
    string dweetContent;//for showing dweet content
    uint public userIdCounter;
    Dweet[] dweetArray;
    mapping (address => Dweet) dweetToUser;
    mapping (address => User) users; //for map user with address for attach dweets
    mapping ( uint => User) userById;
    mapping (uint => Dweet) dweetById;

//constructor
constructor()
{
    owner=msg.sender;
}

//structs
struct Dweet
{
    uint dweetId;
    string content;
    uint liked;
    uint disliked;
    uint reported;
    bool deleted; 
    uint[] whoLikedMe;
    uint[] whoDislikedMe;
    uint whoLikedMeCounter;
    uint whoDislikedMeCounter;
}

struct User
{
    uint userId;
    string name;
    bool isRegistered;
    
    uint followers;
    uint following;
    
    uint[] whoFollowMe;
    uint[] iFollowWhom;
    uint[] likedDweets;
    
    uint[] dislikedDweets;
    Dweet[] UserAllDweets;
    uint userDweetCounter;
    uint followIndex;
}

//functions
function registerUser(string memory _name) public
{
    require ( msg.sender!=owner,"Owner cant register");
    require ( users[msg.sender].isRegistered==false,"You are already registered! ");
    userIdCounter++;
    User memory user = User(userIdCounter, _name, true, 0, 0,
                            new uint[](0),new uint[](0),
                            new uint [](0),new uint[](0),new Dweet[](0),0, 0);
    users[msg.sender]=user;
    userById[userIdCounter]=user;
}

function dweeet(string memory _content) public
{
    require(msg.sender!=owner,"Owner cant dweeet");//should not be owner
    require ( users[msg.sender].isRegistered==true,"User is not registered yet");//user should exist
    dweetCounter++;
    Dweet memory dweet = Dweet ( dweetCounter, _content ,0, 0, 0, false, new uint[](0), new uint[](0), 0, 0);//creating dweet instance
    users[msg.sender].userDweetCounter++;
    users[msg.sender].UserAllDweets[users[msg.sender].userDweetCounter];//storing dweet in resp. user's array
    dweetById[dweetCounter]=dweet;
}

function searchUser( uint _userId ) public view returns(User memory)
{
    User memory u =userById[_userId];
    return u;
}

function followUser( uint  _userId   ) public
{
    require ( userById[_userId].userId != users[msg.sender].userId ,"You cant follow yourself ");
    require(msg.sender!=owner,"You are owner you cant use this function");
    require(users[msg.sender].isRegistered == true,"First register ! ");
    require(userById[_userId].isRegistered==true, " User doesn't exist" );
    
    searchUser(_userId).followers++;
    users[msg.sender].following++;
    
    userById[_userId].followIndex++;
    userById[_userId].whoFollowMe[ userById[_userId].followIndex ] = users[msg.sender].userId;
    
    users[msg.sender].followIndex++;
    users[msg.sender].iFollowWhom[ users[msg.sender].followIndex ] = userById[_userId].userId;
    
}



function unfollowUser( uint _userId) public
{
    require ( userById[_userId].userId != users[msg.sender].userId ,"You cant unfollow yourself ");
    require(msg.sender!=owner,"You are owner you cant use this function");
    require(users[msg.sender].isRegistered == true,"First register ! ");
    require(userById[_userId].isRegistered==true, " User doesn't exist" );
    
    searchUser(_userId).followers--;
    users[msg.sender].following--;
    
    //for getting indexed
    for(uint i=0;i<userById[_userId].followIndex;i++)
    {
        if(userById[_userId].whoFollowMe[i] == users[msg.sender].userId )
        {
            delete userById[_userId].whoFollowMe[i];
        }
        
    }
    userById[_userId].followIndex--;
    
    for(uint i=0;i<users[msg.sender].followIndex;i++)
    {
        if(users[msg.sender].iFollowWhom[i] == userById[_userId].userId )
        {
            delete users[msg.sender].iFollowWhom[i];
        }
        
    }
    users[msg.sender].followIndex--;
    users[msg.sender].iFollowWhom.push(userById[_userId].userId);
    users[msg.sender].following--;

} 

function likeDweet( uint _DweetId) public
{
    require(dweetById[_DweetId].deleted!=true,"Dweet is deleted, cant like");
    require(msg.sender!=owner,"You are owner you cant use this function");
    require(users[msg.sender].isRegistered == true,"First register ! ");
    //for checking if user liking dweet again.
    for(uint i=0;i< dweetById[_DweetId].whoLikedMeCounter;i++)
    {
        if(dweetById[_DweetId].whoLikedMe[i] == users[msg.sender].userId)
        {
            require( false, "You already liked this dweet, Can't like again! ");
        }
    }
    // if user liking disliked tweet. 
    for(uint i=0;i< dweetById[_DweetId].whoDislikedMeCounter;i++)
    {
        if(dweetById[_DweetId].whoDislikedMe[i] == users[msg.sender].userId)
        {
            require( false, "You already disliked this dweet, Can't like now ! ");
        }
    }
            
    
    
    dweetById[_DweetId].liked++;
    users[msg.sender].likedDweets.push(_DweetId);
    
    dweetById[_DweetId].whoLikedMeCounter++;
    dweetById[_DweetId].whoLikedMe[ dweetById[_DweetId].whoLikedMeCounter ]=users[msg.sender].userId;
    
}

function dislikeDweet( uint _DweetId) public
{
    require(dweetById[_DweetId].deleted!=true,"Dweet is deleted, cant like");
    require(msg.sender!=owner,"You are owner you cant use this function");
    require(users[msg.sender].isRegistered == true,"First register ! ");
    //for checking if user disliking dweet again.
    for(uint i=0;i< dweetById[_DweetId].whoDislikedMeCounter;i++)
    {
        if(dweetById[_DweetId].whoDislikedMe[i] == users[msg.sender].userId)
        {
            require( false, "You already diliked this dweet, Can't like again! ");
        }
    }
    
    
    // if user disliking liked tweet. 
    for(uint i=0;i< dweetById[_DweetId].whoLikedMeCounter;i++)
    {
        if(dweetById[_DweetId].whoLikedMe[i] == users[msg.sender].userId)
        {
            require( false, "You already liked this dweet, Can't dislike now ! ");
        }
    }
    
    dweetById[_DweetId].disliked++;
    users[msg.sender].dislikedDweets.push(_DweetId);
    
    dweetById[_DweetId].whoDislikedMeCounter++;
    dweetById[_DweetId].whoDislikedMe[ dweetById[_DweetId].whoDislikedMeCounter ]=users[msg.sender].userId;
    
}


function deleteDweet(uint _dweetId) public
{
    require(dweetById[_dweetId].deleted!=true,"Dweet is already deleted");
    dweetById[_dweetId].deleted=true;
    dweetCounter--;
    
    
}

function reportDweet( uint _DweetId) public
{
    require(dweetById[_DweetId].deleted!=true,"Dweet is deleted");
    
    if(dweetById[_DweetId].reported==15)
    {
        deleteDweet(_DweetId);
    }
    dweetById[_DweetId].reported++;
}

function fetchDweet( uint _dweetId) public
{
    require (dweetById[_dweetId].deleted==false,"This dweet is deleted! ");
    require ( _dweetId<=dweetCounter,"Invalid dweet Id");
    dweetContent=dweetById[_dweetId].content;

}

function showDweet() public view returns(string memory)
{
    return dweetContent;
}

function userDweetCount(uint _userId) public view returns(uint)
{
    uint e=userById[_userId].userDweetCounter;
    return e;
}

function seeFollowers() public view returns( uint)
{
    uint w=users[msg.sender].followers;
    return w;
}

function seeFollowing() public view returns( uint)
{
    uint w=users[msg.sender].following;
    return w;
}

// for knowing whose account is it (test purpose) 
function showMyName() public view returns(string memory)
{
    string memory a =users[msg.sender].name;
    return a;
}

function totalLikes(uint _dweetId) public view returns(uint )
{
     return dweetById[_dweetId].whoLikedMeCounter;
}
function totalDisikes(uint _dweetId) public view returns(uint )
{
     return dweetById[_dweetId].whoDislikedMeCounter;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you should open the contract file and klick on compile
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to precise *"the why"*, but I know how to fix it. Problem is when using `new uint[]()` to initialise a struct value. You just need to replace function `registerUser()` for the one below;

```
function registerUser(string memory _name) public
{
    require(msg.sender != owner, "Owner cant register");
    require(users[msg.sender].isRegistered == false, "You are already registered! ");
    userIdCounter++;
    User memory user;
    // Initialise only with the relevant fields
    user.userId = userIdCounter;
    user.name = _name;
    user.isRegistered = true;
    users[msg.sender] = user;
    userById[userIdCounter] = user;
}
```

The workaround is basically initialising only the relevant values of the struct, instead of assigning all values including the empty arrays.